# Count Number of Unique 2-Field Combinations in QGIS Table

Tags: pyqgis

I have a table where properties are identified by their PID.  A property can have multiple civic address points (e.g. larger buildings), but even when they do they still tend to border on only one street.

For example in the table below Property #3459 has three civic addresses that all border on Main Street:

```
PID    CIVIC   STREET
3459   330     Main
2309   255     Quinpool
0014   26      Main
0187   99      Summer
NULL   NULL    NULL
3459   332     Main
2309   4890    Oxford
3459   334     Main
```

BUT... Property #2309 is one of those rare cases that borders on MORE than one street (perhaps it's a corner lot).

I want to select all properties (like #2309) that border on MORE than one street.
In other words, select all rows with MORE THAN ONE unique PID/STREET combination.

What is the simplest way to achieve this in QGIS python scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script selects at the very end all features being part of multiple combinations. It finds #2309. I have extended the list by an adress PID 3459, STREET Oxford, to deal with cases, where PIDs border at streets with equal AND different names (3x Main, 1x Oxford).

Properties with all NULL attributes are ignored.

```
# get reference to the layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# dict to hold PID as keys, and STREET and id as values
unique = {}  # 

# set to hold id of features being member of combinations 
multiple = set([])

for feat in layer.getFeatures():

    # if a PID is already in the dict
    if unique.get(feat['PID'], None) is not None:

        # but STREET is different, its a multiple combination
        if feat['STREET'] != unique[feat['PID']]['STREET']:
            # add it to the set
            multiple.add(feat.id())
            multiple.update(unique[feat['PID']]['ID'])
        else:
            # STREET is equal, so add id, maybe another STREET is different
            unique[feat['PID']]['ID'].add(feat.id())
    else:
        # otherwise add it to the dict
        unique[feat['PID']] = {'STREET': feat['STREET'], 'ID': set([feat.id()])}

# finally select features with their ids in the set
layer.setSelectedFeatures(list(multiple))
```

Comment: This code works but with the following curiosity: occasional civic points are left out when they should be included in  the selection of civic points within PIDs (properties) that have civic pts of multiple street addresses.  Hopefully that isn't too confusing, a screen grab of my results using your code would illustrate this much better.  But missing the odd point here and there appears not to be consequential because this only appears to happen on PIDs with many civic pts and there always appears to at least one from each street that gets represented in the "multiple" set.

Comment: Hmm, could you extend the data example with such a set? I have to step through the code to get an idea whats going on

Comment: My real data set is very large, but I have a small "test" data set that illustrates this.  I could send it to you if you'd like?  Thanks for your solution too!

Comment: @user3309182 ok, maybe I have missed some case. neumann dot detlev at gmail dot com

Comment: great, just sent you my test data.